# In Orbeon Forms, is form version information available in the REST API?

Tags: orbeon

The documentation says:

In addition, the Oracle, MySQL, and DB2 implementations support versioning to some level, in that it keeps older versions. However this is not visible at the level of the REST API. If all you need is keep older versions in the database, what the Oracle, MySQL, and DB2 implementation does might be sufficient. The best will be for Form Runner and Form Builder to handle versioning natively.

http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api#TOC-Support-for-versioning

Does this mean we can't see form versions at all in the REST API?

Also, I would like to access the USERNAME of the form data owner via the REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation was not quite up to date and I have now clarified the section you are quoting.

The bottom line:

- Versioning of *form definition* is [implemented since Orbeon Forms 4.5](http://blog.orbeon.com/2014/02/form-versioning.html). This is exposed at the API layer via the `Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version` header. But the documentation of this header is lacking.
- There is no versioning of *form data* (so nothing exposed at the API level either).

As a separate feature, the relational persistence implementation never deletes database rows, which allows for auditing of changes (including form definitions and form data). There is no API exposed for this.

Comment: Thanks, @ebruchez. The `ORBEON_FORM_DATA` table does contain a FORM_VERSION column. It looks like the version of form data is exposed via the `Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version` header (need this in the doc). This is good. We had envisioned a form data processor that is version-aware. This would prove more challenging if the version were not exposed. Ideally version would be exposed in both data.xml (perhaps as an attribute of `<form>`) and in /search. Version could be useful to display on the summary page of a form.

Comment: Also, @ebruchez, in the section I referred to the last sentence, in #3 is incomplete.

Comment: The version stored in `orbeon_form_data.form_version` is the form definition version, so that a piece of data is associated to a particular form definition version. That's what the `Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version ` header exposes. Versioning form data would mean being able to save multiple versions of the data, say each time the users presses the "Save" button.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean by "There is no versioning of form data". That's fine. I don't have any need for that. I understood that `orbeon_form_data.form_version` is the form definition version. That is what I need. Thanks, again @ebruchez.