# Orbeon versioning via CRUD

Tags: orbeon

After reading the documentation about the new 4.6 versioning feature and this post [In Orbeon Forms, is form version information available in the REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852111/in-orbeon-forms-is-form-version-information-available-in-the-rest-api) I was wondering how the form builder receives the published version number?

In this screenshot from the builder [image]

you see the latest published version has the value 5. 
How does the builder receive this value and is it possible to accomplish this via our own CRUD interface?

The publishing part we got covered by handling the HTTP_ORBEON_FORM_DEFINITION_VERSION header field and its' value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the python script I used returned the wrong header field.

Anyway the right headerfield both ways is ORBEON-FORM-DEFINITION-VERSION.

So sending this field with the version number results in the right value in the form builder